# Java infinite loop, while validation

Tags: java, loops, validation, infinite-loop

This is a part of my code which is used to validate an input and loop if it is a character, however it causes an infinite loop when a character is input, but works fine when an integer is used. I don't know whats causing the infinite loop but any help would be appreciated.

```
System.out.println("Please type in a mark and enter -1 to end the program");

    while (mark != -1) {

        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            mark = in.nextInt();
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Please input an integer: ");

        }
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Please input an integer: "); in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 1):

If you input a character the:

```
 if (in.hasNextInt())
```

Will return false, and you go to the else, when it loops, the in.hasNextInt() is still false entering the else and looping forever.